# What's causing this weird Windows Phone Emulator crash?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, xna, windows-phone-7

I am trying to debug my Windows Phone 7 app, and I am getting the following error upon launching the app in the emulator (via VS2010 debug):

> Unable to start program
>   '\Windows\tashost.exe\'
>   The drive cannot locate a specific area or track.

Any ideas as what may be causing this? The most recent change I made was adding functionality to save game data, via the `IsolatedStorageFile`. However, it was working for a while with this functionality in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. If only I had read the release notes. For anyone else that might be experiencing this issue, it is addressed in the [WPDT Beta Release Notes.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F4%2FE%2FA%2F4EA52332-C6B1-476E-9938-C4F805146AF5%2FRelease%2520Notes%2520-%2520WPDT%2520Beta.htm&ei=ZfdjTNbfBoSglAflhcT5CQ&usg=AFQjCNHpcxvYpCPiGWTB9ZiK3AjOuzvhuQ&sig2=8iG4h9pnFPfX7o82Fav4GQ)

> Release Notes - WPDT Beta      7/16/2010
>
> Unable to start program error if
>   project not configured to build or
>   deploy. If a project is not configured
>   to build and or deploy a game, the
>   operation will fail with the following
>   error message:
>
> Unable to start program
>   '\Windows\taskhost.exe'.
>   The drive cannot locate a specific area or track
>   on the disk.
>
> To set a game project to
>   build or deploy: In Visual Studio 2010
>   Express for Windows Phone, click
>   Tools, then click Settings, then click
>   Expert Settings to enable the Solution
>   Configurations drop-down. From the
>   Solution Configurations drop-down in
>   the standard toolbar, select
>   Configuration Manager. Check the Build
>   and Deploy checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was to update my graphic card driver.  Even though my computer said the device was up to date, going to the manufacturer website and downloading the latest drive allowed it to work. (using Nvidia by the way) this was after after about 5 hours of trying to figure this thing out.

also make sure you all the rest of your updates are up to date, and that directX is current.